Difficult graph theory problem about number of regular spanning subgraphs
This one is a problem from Korea's math olympiad summer camp this year. The statement is simple.
There are 2024 people in the room. Two people can shake their hands at most once. Let $N_{k}$ be the total number of ways that every person shake their hands with $k$ other people. Which is bigger: $N_{3}$ or $N_{4}$?
It's graph theorical representation will be like this.
Let $N_{k}$ be the total number of k-regular spanning subgraph(not nesessary connected, i.e. can have more than 1 connected component) of complete graph with 2024 vertice. Which is bigger: $N_{3}$ or $N_{4}$?
My approach was using the well-known fact: 4-regular graph can be decomposed into two 2-regular graph. This can be proved by find the euler tour and color it's edge alternately.
So this means every 4-regular spanning subgraph can be corresponded to some pairs of 2-regular spanning subgraph with edges are non-overlapping.
But in this method, I couldn't found how this is related to 3-regular spanning subgraphs. I tried to decompose it into 2-factor and 1-factor, but found out this is only possible when graph is bridgeless.
There must be some neat proof, but I couldn't found out yet. Please help me to find good ways to solve it!!

Here's a clue:  3+1=4

@Brendan McKay I've been thinking about that idea, adding perfect matching to 3-regular spanning subgraph to make 4-regular one. But if we want to use this method, we need to add 'same' matching to every 3-regular graphs. This is because adding two different matchings to two different 3-regular graphs each can make same 4-regular graph. But if you add same matching to every 3-regular graph, this can be impossible since matching's edge and 3-regular graph's edge can be overlapped

Yesterday I solved this and wrote the answer containing only link of the solution, but it is delected because of policy. So I'll write new answer containig full text of my solution. Anyway, it's easier than I thought if this is not a fakesolve.
▪︎ Solution
The problem asks which of two is larger, number of $3-$regular spanning subgraph of $K_{2024}$ and number of $4-$regular spanning subgraph of $K_{2024}$. We'll prove there are more $4-$regular ones then $3-$regular ones.
First, define $A$ be the set of $3-$regular graphs, and $B$ be the set of $4-$regular graphs. And make bipartite graph $G(A, B)$ by connecting $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ iff there exist perfect matching $M$ such that $M$ doesn't have common edge with $a$, and adding $M$ to $a$ makes $b$.
If every vertex in $A$ has larger degree then every vertex in $B$, we're done. This is because if we call minimal degree of $A$ be $d_1$ and maximal degree of $B$ be $d_2$, $|E(G)| \geq d_1|A|$, $|E(G)| \leq d_2|B|$ holds. Since $d_2<d_1$, it means $d_1|A| \leq d_2|B|<d_1|B|$ and $|A|<|B|$ holds.
Degree of $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ is equal to the number of perfect matchings in complement of $a$(which is $2020-$regular spanning subgraph of $K_{2024}$), $b$ each. So it's suffice to show that $2020-$regular graph has more perfect matchings than $4-$regular graph.
We prove it by following two claims. From now, I'll call $k-$regular spanning subgraph of $K_{2024}$ to $k-$regular graph.
Claim 1. Every $2020-$regular graph has perfect matching.
Proof.
Since degree is larger than $\frac{2024}{2}=1012$, It has hamiltonian cycle by Dirac's theorem. Just picking edge of this cycle alternately, we find perfect matching.
Claim 2. Every $2020-$regular graph has at least $(1005)!! \cdot 2^{503}$ perfect matching.
Proof.
Let's number the vertice of graph to $1, ..., 2024$ and WLOG matching in claim 1 was $[1, 2], [3, 4], ..., [2023, 2024]$, and call it $M$. By adding some edges, we'll make $(1005)!!$ types of graphs consist of $503$ $K_4$'s and $6$ $K_2$'s.
First, let's call vertex $x$ and edge $[y, z]$ is couple iff $x$ is connected to both $y, z$.
Pick $[1, 2]$. Each of vertex $1, 2$ has $2019$ neighbors rather than each other, and there are $1011$ remaining matchings. So there is at least $1008$ couple edges to each vertex, and at least $1005$ common couple to $[1, 2]$. Pick one of them has at least $1005$ ways, and it makes first $K_4$ containing $1, 2$.
Next, pick one of remaining $1010$ matching edges. WLOG it was $[5, 6]$. Then each of vertex $5, 6$ has at least $2015$ neighbors rather than each other and $K_4$'s. Since there are $1009$ remaining matchings. So there is at least $1006$ couple edges to each vertex, and at least $1003$ common couple to $[5, 6]$. Pick one of them has at least $1003$ ways, and it makes second $K_4$ containing $5, 6$.
In this way, when we reached $k$th step, we can pick $k$th $K_4$ with at least $1007-2k$ ways, and if we reached final step $k=503$, the number of ways that making $K_4$'s will be at least $1005 \cdot 1003 \cdot ... \cdot 3 \cdot 1=(1005)!!$. And each type will be consist of $503$ $K_4$'s and $6$ $K_2$'s, with all of these graphs are all pairwise different(If two different type $A$, $B$ had made first different choice of making $K_4$ in $r$th step, their $r$th $K_4$ must share exactly two vertice, which means two graphs are different).
So if we make new matchings to each graph by choosing one of two other matchings in each $K_4$ which is not original $M$, we can make exactly $2^{503}$ ones to each types.
It's easy to see they're all different. If they're from same type it's trivial. And if they're from different type, there are two $K_4$ $X$, $Y$ in each type such that $X, Y$ share exactly two vertice $x, y$. $x, y$ must have different matching partner in two chosen matchings. So alltogether, this means there are at least $(1005)!! \cdot 2^{503}$ matchings.
Now it's easy to finish it. Every $4-$regular graph has $\frac{2024 \cdot 4}{2}=4048$ edges, so number of perfect matching is less than $2^{4048}$. But since $(1005)!! \cdot 2^{503}>2^{4048}$(see here), the problem is solved.
▪︎ Comment.
This is original solution link: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3377395p31478052
And I've heard there is much more easier solution while writing this.

Here's easier solution which I mentioned above(it's not mine).
We will show $2020-$regular graph has at least $\frac{(2020)!!}{4}$ perfect matchings, and $4-$regular graph has at most $2^{2024}$ perfect matchings.
1. For $2020-$regular graph
Think abot following algorithm: Pick one vertice $v_1$ and choose one of it's neighbor(call it $v_2$). This makes first edge of matching, and number of choice is $2020$. Then, pick second vertice $v_3(\neq v_1, v_2)$ and choose one of it's neighbor $v_4(\neq v_1, v_2)$. This makes second edge of matching, and number of choice is at least $2018$, since $v_3$'s degree is $2020$ and it can connect to at most two among $v_1, v_2$.
In this way if we reached $k$th step, we already made $k-1$ matchings. Pick new vertice(not choosed yet) $v_{2k-1}$, then it has at least $2020-(2k-2)=2022-2k$ neighbors in remaining vertice. So if we choose one of them(call it $v_{2k}$) we can make $k$th edge of matching with number of choice is at least $2022-2k$. This algorithm continues until finishing $1008$th step.
After finishing $1008$th step, there will be $8$ vertice remainig. Since each remaining vertices have at least $4$ neighbors in another remaining vertices, there is hamiltonian cycle by Dirac's theorem. So we can make rest $4$ edges of perfect matching by alternately choose edges of hamiltonian cycle, and there are $2$ possibilities.
Perfect matchings made by these algorithm are all different, so we can ensure there are at least $2020 \cdot 2018 \cdot ... \cdot 8 \cdot 6 \cdot 2=\frac{(2020)!!}{4}$ perfect matchings.
2. For $4-$ regular graph
We use same algorithm above, but this time we can stop this algorithm when we can't find new vertice. More specifically, think about we reached $k$th step and picked $v_{2k-1}$ among non-choosed vertices. If there is neighbor among non-choosed vertice then we can continue, but there is no neighbor, finish algorithm immediately.
By this algorithm, every step has at most $4$ ways of choice since graph is $4-$regular. So the total number of matchings found by these algorithm is at most $4^{\frac{2024}{2}}=4^{1012}=2^{2024}$.
And it's easy to show that every matching of $4-$regular graph appears in these algorithm. For example, matching $M$ consist of edges $[1, 2], [3, 4], ..., [2023, 2024]$ can appear by this algorithm by following way; If our algorithm first pick vertex $v_1=3$, then $M$ is in subcase when $v_2=4$. Next, if our algorithm pick $v_3=7$ then $M$ is in subcase $v_4=8$, ... Like this, $M$ can be chosen by these algorithm. So this means $4-$regular graph has at most $2^{2024}$ perfect matchings.
Since $\frac{(2020)!!}{4}>2^{2024}$, we're done.
